# Event Monitoring Database + Grafana

Tags: devops, influxdb, grafana, graphite, prometheus

I have the following scenario: I need to monitor an event that may or may not happen twice in a 15 minute periods throughout  the day. e.g someone will log how many people they have interviewed on the street. It may be many, it may be none - but I am interested to see what the stats would look like per 15 min periods in Grafana. I am not interested in seeing the totals at the at of the day.

I have been playing with Graphite + Grafana to do this (sending the info via carbon-cache) but after struggling I am starting to think that perhaps Graphite is not built for this as it seems to expect streaming time based data not intermittent data like mine.

Question: What is the suggested tool for the this task ? Can Graphite do the job ? if yes what would the storage-schemas.conf and storage-aggregation.conf files need to look like ?

**NOTE** I am not asking the SE forbidden question of what is the **best** rather for suggestions of what backends to Grafana I could use to achieve my goal.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the first paragraph. What is the difference of your case and just a simple "see data over the last 15 minutes"? Also, "monitor an event that may or may not happen twice in a 15 minute", you post a data point if event happened? You post it twice if event happened twice?
It is always better to reason about time-series data in terms of data-points to store.

Comment: I understood that time-series db's are good where you have a constant flow of data hitting the DB. In my case I have 1 event every x minutes and even then it may  not even happen.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand the problem... You can write to TSDB with any rate/frequency you want. It is OK to be used this way. Each data point will have a time stamp when it was reported. Then just count points "for the last 15 minutes" and visualize it either with "signlestat" chart for the last 15 mins, or with histogram to see counts history on each 15 minutes.